# iPhone How to programmatically handle SMS/Call alert notification

Tags: iphone, video, sms, call, alert

I'm having some problems with SMS alerts and call notification freezing up the video player. I'm currently displaying a video using MPMoviePlayerController with movieControl Hidden. I'm also overlaying a subtitle using UITextView on top of the video.

However whenever a SMS alert popup, the video will freeze up but the textView will continue to scroll. A call alert will also intrupt the video, causing the video to freeze up while the text continue scrolling, which leads to misallignment.

So is there any way to fix the video from freezing up? Or is there any way to detect SMS/Call alert notifications and handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check

> ```
> - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
> ```

and

> ```
> - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
> ```

methods of UIApplicationDelegate protocol. Or you can catch

> ```
> UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
> ```

and

```
UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
```

notifications

Comment: thz that method seems to be working fine, although it is a bit generic lol